# Deploying a Python API to Azure App Services

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a client with an existing API built in Python 2.7.6.  Currently it's Dockerized (Docker v1.16(?)) on some VMs at another host.  I have seen several posts about putting Python natively on azure app services but I am no expert at either Docker or Python so I wanted to know a couple things:

1. Can we natively push Python (2.7.6) to azure app services? or would
   we need something like Docker?
2. This Docker version is (apparently) quite old - is it easy to update
   this?
3. If I needed to Dockerize this what SKU on Azure would I need to
   procure? I suspect this would not be a standard S1 web app running
   Linux?

Comment: In app services, you can host *either* a dockerized version of your API (single-container only) or a native python api. I'm pretty sure they support both 2.7 or 3.x

Comment: Thanks, i was under the impression that native Python was preview mode only and required FLASK based python implementation.  this is in Django - i really know nothing about Python - I am not too concerned about the preview mode, but do you know if Django framework based Python code could be natively deployed?

Comment: Actually, my previous comment needs revision, they do support multi-container applications. Their documentation only mentions Flask, and there isn't much from what I can see surrounding installing other packages. I think the workaround there could be to include the django source in your zipped build, but that seems to be a bit overkill. Again, take that with a grain of salt, I have only deployed container services to get rid of the headache of dependency management

Comment: thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Following link explains creation of app services using docker hub image: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go

More detailed explanation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

You can also use webapp on linux to deploy your python app directly: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python

If you are using direct deployment, use Webapp for Linux, rather than Webapp for windows. Windows based webapp are mmore suited for dotnet based applications